# iPhone: Navigation from button

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationcontroller

Hey guys I have a RootViewController that has his nib file RootView.nib. Anyways there's a button that when you press is it sends you to my SecondViewController(SecondViewController also has his SecondViewController.nib file).

Now the SecondViewController has an IBOutlet UINavigationController and has also the delegate from NavigationController.

But I can make the app to start the navigation from the second view, I tried connecting everything in the IB, but nothing has worked.

I need help with this, the app needs the navigation from the second view.
Best Regards
Carlos Vargas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm I already solve this, I had nothing to do with the IB.

just added an UINavigationController *nav to the the RootViewController and then did this:

> SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:...];
>
> nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:second];
>
> [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:NO];
>
> [nav release];[second release];